# fetching html element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have following html code

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#tab-One" class="tabLink">This is tab one</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab-Two" class="tabLink">This is tab two</a></li>
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

How could I fetch this string to some js variable `One` or `Two` (this will be ofcourse dynamic data).
This string is exactly between `#tab-` and `class=`

Comment: You forgot to post your jQuery code.

Comment: `var One = $('#tabs .tabLink').eq(0).attr('href').replace('#tab-','');`

Comment: @adeneo Tried your approach it always selected first element One, I need to fetch onclick data, tabOne, tabTwo, etc.

Comment: Yes, It targets only the first one, that's what `eq(0)` does, I left the rest up to you to figure out ;-) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this on click, you could do the following

```
var activeTab = null;
$('#tabs .tabLink').click(function() {
    activeTab = $(this).attr('href').split('-')[1];
    window.alert(activeTab);
});
```

Comment: tried, nothing selected. any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean `$(this).attr` or `this.href`

Comment: Solved! $(this).attr('href').split('-')[1]; Thanks Explosion Pills and TheSmose

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $("#tabs .tabLink[href='#tab-" + someJsVar + "']").text();
```

Comment: what does someJsVar represents here? I need to grab data from dynamicly  rendered items (tabOne, tabTwo, TabThree, ...). Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

This will iterate through all of the .tabLinks and grab the value you're looking for.

```
$('#tabs').find('.tabLink').each(function(i,el){
    alert($(el).attr('href').replace('#tab-',''))
});​
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This outputs exactly what the OP requested. They did not specify how it would be used, via click, .each(), etc.